# Query to sum the top "n" records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to sum the forecast qty column for only the first "n" date records.  For example for each item number the earliest(or first) three date records

Current Query:

```
SELECT gen.Item ,
        gen.DemandDate ,
        gen.ForecastQty 
FROM reports.v_special_demand_800 gen 
ORDER BY gen.Item, gen.DemandDate ASC
```

Table

[image]

Desired Result

[image]

Comment: Why 52? What is the logic that are you looking for? Welcome to S.O. Please read the guidelines on how to ask in order we can help you.

Comment: You might want to clarify/verify that you really want the most recent 52 dates, and not something else?  52 makes it seem that each date happens to occur in a separate week, over the course of an entire year.  But adding sample data to your question can resolve this.

Comment: Please post your data as text not image

Comment: ??? ___Tim, I am using Microsoft SQL___  Then WHY do you tag MYSQL?????? Dont spam tags they are there to gather the correct audience for your question. Use then incorrectly all you get is an angry mob

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a row number to each record, partitioning by Item (this will start a new row counter for each Item) and ordering by DemandDate. Then sum the records where the row number is <= N, grouping by Item:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY DemandDate) as RowNum
    FROM reports.v_special_demand_800
)
SELECT Item, SUM(ForecastQty)
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum <= 3
GROUP BY Item
```

Comment: This worked for me, I really appreciate the quick response and resolve with this Michael!